# How could I use GPU in google colab to train spacy relation extraction model, [E002] Can't find factory for 'transformer' for language English (en)

Tags: gpu, google-colaboratory, relation, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I am running a relation extraction spacy model on google colab , It works when I use `!spacy project run all` or `!spacy project run train_cpu` but when I run `!spacy project run train_gpu` it returns following error:

```
================================= train_gpu =================================
Running command: /usr/bin/python3 -m spacy train configs/rel_trf.cfg --output training --paths.train data/train.spacy --paths.dev data/dev.spacy -c ./scripts/custom_functions.py --gpu-id 0
ℹ Saving to output directory: training
ℹ Using GPU: 0

=========================== Initializing pipeline ===========================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spacy/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup_cli()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spacy/cli/_util.py", line 71, in setup_cli
    command(prog_name=COMMAND)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/typer/main.py", line 497, in wrapper
    return callback(**use_params)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spacy/cli/train.py", line 45, in train_cli
    train(config_path, output_path, use_gpu=use_gpu, overrides=overrides)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spacy/cli/train.py", line 72, in train
    nlp = init_nlp(config, use_gpu=use_gpu)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spacy/training/initialize.py", line 41, in init_nlp
    nlp = load_model_from_config(raw_config, auto_fill=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spacy/util.py", line 531, in load_model_from_config
    validate=validate,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spacy/language.py", line 1784, in from_config
    raw_config=raw_config,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spacy/language.py", line 794, in add_pipe
    validate=validate,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spacy/language.py", line 652, in create_pipe
    raise ValueError(err)
ValueError: [E002] Can't find factory for 'transformer' for language English (en). This usually happens when spaCy calls `nlp.create_pipe` with a custom component name that's not registered on the current language class. If you're using a Transformer, make sure to install 'spacy-transformers'. If you're using a custom component, make sure you've added the decorator `@Language.component` (for function components) or `@Language.factory` (for class components).

Available factories: attribute_ruler, tok2vec, merge_noun_chunks, merge_entities, merge_subtokens, token_splitter, doc_cleaner, parser, beam_parser, entity_linker, ner, beam_ner, entity_ruler, lemmatizer, tagger, morphologizer, senter, sentencizer, textcat, spancat, textcat_multilabel, relation_extractor, en.lemmatizer
```

I used both following installations (interchangeably) in case the GPU wasn't called correctly:
!pip install -U spacy[cuda101]
#!pip install -U spacy-nightly --pre

Answer (score 1):

You haven't installed `spacy-transformers`. The easiest way to do this is probably to `spacy download en_core_web_trf`.

I would recommend you check the [install quickstart](https://spacy.io/usage#quickstart) again - I don't think `spacy-nightly` has been updated since v3 was released almost a year ago. Also check the [Discussions FAQ](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8226) - it's been a while since we've heard reports of it, but a while ago you had to specifically *not* install cupy (that is, not use `pip install spacy[cuda101]`) in order to get GPU support on Colab.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, Actually, I used to install transformers like this; !pip install spacy-transformers. Anyways I followed your suggestions and now, the new error appears, ValueError: [E1014] Error loading DocBin data. It doesn't look like the data is in DocBin (.spacy) format. . I found a post in git hub that addressed this issue dealing with dev, spacy file, but I have this file on the proper directory, It turned out that the .spycy files I used in this project were corrupted, changed them and it works

Comment: it created a model but it cannot be loaded  due to this error: ValueError: [E002] Can't find factory for 'relation_extractor' for language English (en). This usually happens when spaCy calls `nlp.create_pipe` with a custom component name that's not registered on the current language class. If you're using a Transformer, make sure to install 'spacy-transformers'. If you're using a custom component, make sure you've added the decorator `@Language.component` (for function components) or `@Language.factory` (for class components).

Available factories: attribute_ruler, tok2vec, merge_noun_c...

Comment: Don't ask further questions in comments, it's really hard to follow what's going on. You can ask a new question here, but it seems like your question might be better suited for the spaCy forums. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions