# Spacy ValueError: [E002] Can't find factory for 'relation_extractor' for language English (en)

Tags: nlp, spacy

I want to train a "relation extractor" component as in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HL-Ap5_Axo). I have 3 .spacy files (train.spacy, dev.spacy, test.spacy.

I run:

```
python3 -m spacy init fill-config config.cfg config.cfg
```

followed by

```
python3 -m spacy train --output ./model config.cfg --paths.train train.spacy --paths.dev dev.spacy
```

Output:

```
ValueError: [E002] Can't find factory for 'relation_extractor' for language English (en). This usually happens when spaCy calls `nlp.create_pipe` with a custom component name that's not registered on the current language class. If you're using a Transformer, make sure to install 'spacy-transformers'. If you're using a custom component, make sure you've added the decorator `@Language.component` (for function components) or `@Language.factory` (for class components).

Available factories: attribute_ruler, tok2vec, merge_noun_chunks, merge_entities, merge_subtokens, token_splitter, doc_cleaner, parser, beam_parser, lemmatizer, trainable_lemmatizer, entity_linker, ner, beam_ner, entity_ruler, tagger, morphologizer, senter, sentencizer, textcat, spancat, future_entity_ruler, span_ruler, textcat_multilabel, en.lemmatizer
```

I have tried the two config files [here](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/tutorials/rel_component/configs) but the output is the same.

To enable Transformers I have installed spacy-transformers downloaded en_core_web_trf via

```
python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_trf
```

A similar issue was mentioned [on GitHub](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/7378) but that solution is for an other context. Similarly, [on GitHub](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/7345) somebody raised the same issue with no solution. [Here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70809137/how-could-i-use-gpu-in-google-colab-to-train-spacy-relation-extraction-model-e) was not solved.

Comment: The first thing you link to on Github has the solution - you have to import the code from the example project, because the relation extractor is not included in spaCy core. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/7378#discussioncomment-461542